# use css to align different fields instead of using table

Tags: html, css

I have something like below.  Book name (can be variable length, got from an ajax call), price, and quantity. Is there a way I can align each field using CSS instead of using a table to do that?  Thanks.

e.g. HTML output:

```
Emacs Handbook $10 1
Web Development In 10 Days $20 2
Car $8 3
```

I want:

```
Emacs Handbook             $10   1
Web Development In 10 Days $20   2
Car                        $8    1
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you need to display data in a tabular manner, use tables - that's what they are for.

Comment: Yes there are ways, but that *is* tabular data

Comment: is this more related to layout?  i am trying to avoid using table for layout purpose.

Comment: Separate your thinking of "Layout" and "Content."  A table of values is in the content realm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using tables.  If it's tabular data (ie something one would expect in an excel spreadsheet or a database table), it still belongs in a table.

If you must insist, you could put each of those in a span inside a list item and then style them:

HTML:

```
<ul class="productList">
    <li>
        <span class="title">Emacs Handbook</span> 
        <span class="price">$50</span> 
        <span class="qty">3</span
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.productList span { display:inline-block;}
.productList .title { width:250px;}
.productList .price { width:50px;}
.productList .qty { width: 50px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Psuedo:

Get longest title length; 
Get longest price length;

Then, use javascript to set the css of each holder of title, price, and length, to be

for title { left: 0px;}

for price { left: title length + buffer size (10px?)}

for quantity { left: title length + buffer size + price length + buffer size}

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .super-container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 900px;
    }
    .table {
      float: left;
      margin-bottom: 0.5em;
      text-indent: 0.2em;
      padding: 0.1em;
      width: 100%;
    }  
    .table-header {
      font: bold 1.3em tahoma;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .table-description {
      display: block;
      font: italic 0.8em tahoma;
      text-indent: 0.6em;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .field-header {
      font: bold 1em tahoma;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .field-header, .row {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      padding-top: 0.1em;
      padding-bottom: 0.1em;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .field-header li, .row li {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      font-size: 1em;
      height: 1.4em;
      line-height: 1.4em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body><div class="super-container">
  <div id="table1" class="table">
    <h4 class="table-header" colspan="4">
      tbl name
    </h4>
    <span class="table-description" colspan="4">
      this is my tbl description
    </span>
    <ul class="field-header">
      <li id="a">A</li>
      <li id="b">B</li>
      <li id="c">C</li>
      <li id="d">D</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="row">
      <li id="a"><a href="#">1a</a></li>
      <li id="b"><a href="#">1b</a></li>
      <li id="c"><a href="#">1c</a></li>
      <li id="d"><a href="#">1d</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="row">
      <li id="a"><a href="#">2a</a></li>
      <li id="b"><a href="#">2b</a></li>
      <li id="c"><a href="#">2c</a></li>
      <li id="d"><a href="#">2d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- end table -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var widths = {
        'a': '20%',
        'b': '50%',
        'c': '10%',
        'd': '10%'
      }
      setColumnWidths('#table1', "individually", widths);
    });

    /**
     * Set column widths of `tableless` table see above example html
     * @param tbl The id of the table as string
     * @param how How the function should set the table width as string
     * @param widths Key value pairs fieldId: value e.g { 'field1': '10px' }
     */
    function setColumnWidths(tbl, how, widths) {
      var tblRowElements = $(tbl + ' > ul');
      var tblColElements = tblRowElements.children();
      var numberOfRows = tblRowElements.length;
      var numberOfCols = tblColElements.length / numberOfRows;

      switch(how) {
        case "evenly":
          tblColElements.width( (100/numberOfCols + "%") );
          break;
        case "individually":
          var getWidth = function(property) {
            return widths[property];
          }
          tblColElements.each(function(widths){
            var elm = $(this);
            var elmId = elm.attr('id');
            elm.width(getWidth(elmId));
          });
          break;
        default:
          alert("unknown how arg passed: " + how
                  + "\n reverting to default `evenly`");
          setColumnWidths(tbl, "evenly");
          break;
      }  
    }

    </script>
  </div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree about using tables in this situation, but if you want to use css (and a little jquery) you could use Calvin's html:

```
<ul class="productList">
    <li>
        <span class="title">Emacs Handbook</span>
        <span class="price">$10</span>
        <span class="qty">1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="title">Web Development In 10 Days</span>
        <span class="price">$10</span>
        <span class="qty">1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="title">Car</span>
        <span class="price">$10</span>
        <span class="qty">1</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And a little bit of jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.title').css('width',getMaxNameWidth());
});

function getMaxNameWidth(){
  var maxWidth = 0;
  $('.title').each(function(i){
    if(this.offsetWidth > maxWidth)
      maxWidth = this.offsetWidth;
  });
  return maxWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A list-like DOM is possible:

HTML (took from Calvin Froedge):

```
<ul class="productList">
    <li>
        <span class="title">Emacs Handbook</span> 
        <span class="price">$50</span> 
        <span class="qty">3</span
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.productList { display: table; }
.productList > li { display: table-row; }
.productList > li > * { display: table-cell; }
```

But there's no need to use list elements and even spans to distinguish cells. You have tabular data, so you should use table elements - which cause no css problems in older browsers. I only use that solution when I'm already having semantic tags there, e.g. a list of labels and inputs.